# Register variables with dynamic names from with_items

Tags: ansible

I would like to register variables from lookup results.
My inventory:

```yaml
rrules:
  - name: r1
    start_date: '2022-01-01 13:00:00'
  - name: r2
    start_date: '2022-02-02 12:00:00'
```

Task looks like:

```yaml
- name: Create a string for a schedule
  debug:
    msg: "{{ query('awx.awx.schedule_rrule', 'minute', start_date=item.start_date) }}"
  register: "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ rrules }}"
```

When I run the playbook, I get the error:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid variable name in 'register' specified: '{{ item.name }}'"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `register` of a `debug` task is a terrible idea.
**Do not do that**, instead, use the proper module to register variables, which is the [`set_fact` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html).

With it, you can register variable with a dynamic name, as you intended it:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    "{{ item.name }}": >-
      {{ query(
          'awx.awx.schedule_rrule',
          'minute',
          start_date=item.start_date
      ) }}
  loop: "{{ rrules }}"
```

---

Given those tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    "{{ item.name }}": >-
      {{ query(
          'awx.awx.schedule_rrule',
          'minute',
          start_date=item.start_date
      ) }}
  loop: "{{ rrules }}"
  vars:
    rrules:
      - name: r1
        start_date: '2022-01-01 13:00:00'
      - name: r2
        start_date: '2022-02-02 12:00:00'

- debug:
    var: r1

- debug:
    var: r2
```

It will yield:

```
TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'r1', 'start_date': '2022-01-01 13:00:00'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'r2', 'start_date': '2022-02-02 12:00:00'})

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  r1: DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:20220101T130000 RRULE:FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  r2: DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:20220202T120000 RRULE:FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1
```